# How can I autoplay a video in an iframe tag without muting it?

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, autoplay

I have developed a feature on my website where the video automatically plays, similar to TikTok, when a user visits. The video is embedded using the iframe tag.

I have tried many methods but without success, and I have found information that this is Google's policy where autoplaying videos must be muted. However, I don't understand why TikTok can do it do.
Can you help me resolve it? Thanks you!